# Why does chat alert (ping) me when a similar user is being talked to?

Tags: bug, chat, notifications

Today I got a nice chat message notification (ping) and got really excited that I finally have some friends to talk to, but to my dismay they weren't trying to talk to me but to a user with a similar username:

- me = [@Mooz](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/21267/mooz)
- Other person = [@Moo](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/30807/moo)

Confusing, I know...

[Here is the relevant chat transcript](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19114100#19114100). When **@Major Stackings** sent [this message](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19113892#19113892), *I* got the notification (sounds, little asterisk in my chat window, etc)...

**What is going on here?**

Comment: Possible that you were originally tagged, and then Major Stackings went back and edited it to @ the correct user?

Comment: Oh yeah, that makes sense.

Comment: No. I'm sure sent it to @Moo from my cellphone and didn't go back in and edit it.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73931/226928

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of the pitfalls of the chat notification system being "smart" rather than dumb.

According to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73931/getting-marcs-chat-notifications) on SE: Meta when the system detects the use of a name in the chat box, it attempts to route the notification to the correct user. Unfortunately this sometimes results in another user with a similar name being sent the notification incorrectly.

> [The System will] generate a notification for you ... when we
>   can't find anyone else who we consider to be a better match, i.e.
>   someone called "Marc" who was in the room during the past seven days,
>   or someone called "Marc Gravell" who was here in the past two days.

As the saying goes; it's not a bug, it's a feature.

Comment: [It's not a bug, it's a feature](http://www.webigence.com/resources/images/blog/Bug_feature1.jpg).